# Encode and Decode rfc2396 URLs in Nim

Tags: url, urlencode, nim-lang, urldecode, rfc2396

I'm working on an application that will work as a cli trash app (I know trash-cli exists, this is a personal project :) ), one of the problems I encountered is that your trash info (when you move something to trash, an info file is generated to store it's original location) stores the info in **RFC 2396** format, so spaces becomes `%20` and an opening bracket becomes an `%28`. (here is an example: `/home/netsu/Documents/Music%20%28copy%29`)

My question is, how can I convert `/home/netsu/Documents/Music (copy)` into `/home/netsu/Documents/Music%20%28copy%29` and vice versa in Nim? Python has things like `urllib.urlencode` which I believe does this, but I don't know of such a useful feature in Nim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at uri.encodeUrl and uri.decodeUrl: https://nim-lang.org/docs/uri.html#encodeUrl%2Cstring